# Execute jQuery script on page load in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid of images that have a certain width and height. I needed them to be a square and so I did this using jQuery by getting the width value and assigning it to the height. The code goes like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var width = $(".post-size-2x2")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        $('.post-size-2x2').css({
            'height': width + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it that *the grid first renders with the default size and after 3-4 seconds when the page has fully loaded, then this script executes. I'm guessing this has something to do with*

> "jQuery(document).ready(function($)" ...

**How to fix this, so that the script executes immediately on page load?**

Comment: try calling `$(window).resize();` right after `.ready()` function and before your `resize` function. (btw $(document).ready` is faster than `onload` if you were wondering)